# Como manter o Scroll na ultima posição após atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Realizei algumas tentativas, mas não tive sucesso...
A prioridade é que seja em JavaScript puro... Mas como não consegui, tentei com jQuery também.

A situação seria, cada vez que o usuário aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade no input, a página atualiza e o Scroll deverá manter sua ultima posição. No meu caso ele está indo para o topo.

Algumas das minhas tentativas foram:

```js
//1)  
var posicaoScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
$(document).scrollTop(posicaoScroll);

//2) "cart-table__product" é a classe a minha lista de produtos no carrinho
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cart-table__product').attr({scrollTop: $('.cart-table__product').attr('scrollHeight')});
});

//3)
function scroll() {
  var objScrDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-table__product");
  objScrDiv.scrollTop = objScrDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei um script usando JavaScript puro que salva a última posição do Scroll da janela no `localstorage`, ele verifica sempre no carregamento da página se existe alguma posição salva, se sim, ele muda a posição do Scroll baseado nela.

```
var posicao = localStorage.getItem('posicaoScroll');

/* Se existir uma opção salva seta o scroll nela */
if(posicao) {
    /* Timeout necessário para funcionar no Chrome */
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, posicao);
    }, 1);
}

/* Verifica mudanças no Scroll e salva no localStorage a posição */
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    posicao = window.scrollY;
    localStorage.setItem('posicaoScroll', JSON.stringify(posicao));
}
```

[Funcionando no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naf7eqxg/)

Comment: Obrigado @Dobrychtop funcionou!